# How to create a cube in swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, cube

I am trying to make a class that when invoked by a `JPanel`, creates a cube. What I have seen though, is something called a `ColorCube`, which requires a  "*`Universe`*" of some sort, and a `Canvas`, though I didn't find this method to be compatible with `JPanel`.

TO clarify, I am not asking how to create a custom `JComponent`(exactly), nor am I asking how to add color or rotate  it, just how to create a class that when invoked by a `JPanel` renders a cube to the screen.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a custom JComponent that displays a 3D drawing of a cube where the user can change the color of the cube?

Comment: You want a 3D cube, that can be rotated, etc??

Comment: Images help, in trying to convey what you are trying to achieve

Comment: i edited post to clarify

Comment: im not sure the edit is any clearer :/

Comment: I just wanna know how to make a class that renders a cube to a jframe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you really need are `x, y, and size` passed to the `Cube` class, then

- Take those arguments and build an array of corners points for a first square and also corner points for a second shifted square. See methods `getCubeOnePoints` and `getCubeTwoPoints` methods in the `Cube` class.
- Draw the first square. Draw the second square, and connect the points from the point arrays. See the `drawCube` method in the `Cube` class.
- Create an instance of the `Cube` class passing necessary arguments, and draw the cube. See `CubePanel` constructor and `paintComponent` method

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CubePanel extends JPanel{
    private static final int D_W = 400;
    private static final int D_H = 400;

    Cube cube;
    public CubePanel() {
        cube = new Cube(75, 75, 200, 50);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        cube.drawCube(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

    public class Cube {
        int x, y, size, shift;
        Point[] cubeOnePoints;
        Point[] cubeTwoPoints;
        public Cube(int x, int y, int size, int shift) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.size = size;
            this.shift = shift;
            cubeOnePoints = getCubeOnePoints();
            cubeTwoPoints = getCubeTwoPoints();
        }

        private Point[] getCubeOnePoints() {
            Point[] points = new Point[4];
            points[0] = new Point(x, y);
            points[1] = new Point(x + size, y);
            points[2] = new Point(x + size, y + size);
            points[3] = new Point(x, y + size);
            return points;
        }

        private Point[] getCubeTwoPoints() {
            int newX = x + shift;
            int newY = y + shift;
            Point[] points = new Point[4];
            points[0] = new Point(newX, newY);
            points[1] = new Point(newX + size, newY);
            points[2] = new Point(newX + size, newY + size);
            points[3] = new Point(newX, newY + size);
            return points;
        }

        public void drawCube(Graphics g) {
            g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
            g.drawRect(x + shift, y + shift, size, size);
            // draw connecting lines
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                g.drawLine(cubeOnePoints[i].x, cubeOnePoints[i].y, 
                        cubeTwoPoints[i].x, cubeTwoPoints[i].y);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new CubePanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE

> "what if i wanted this in a 3d where the cube could be walked around "

Just create methods to shift *all* the `x`s or `y`s and call it, then repaint.  The method could look something like

```
    public void shiftLeft() {
        x -= SHIFT_INC;
        for (Point p : cubeOnePoints) {
            p.x -= SHIFT_INC;
        }
        for (Point p : cubeTwoPoints) {
            p.x -= SHIFT_INC;
        }
    }
```

In the example below, I just call it in a key bind with the <kbd>←</kbd>key.

```
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "shiftLeft");
    getActionMap().put("shiftLeft", new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cube.shiftLeft();
            repaint();
        }
    });
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CubePanel extends JPanel{
    private static final int D_W = 400;
    private static final int D_H = 300;

    Cube cube;
    public CubePanel() {
        cube = new Cube(75, 75, 50, 15);
        InputMap im = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "shiftRight");
        getActionMap().put("shiftRight", new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cube.shiftRight();
                repaint();
            }
        });
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "shiftLeft");
        getActionMap().put("shiftLeft", new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cube.shiftLeft();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        cube.drawCube(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

    public class Cube {
        private static final int SHIFT_INC = 5;
        int x, y, size, shift;
        Point[] cubeOnePoints;
        Point[] cubeTwoPoints;
        public Cube(int x, int y, int size, int shift) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.size = size;
            this.shift = shift;
            cubeOnePoints = getCubeOnePoints();
            cubeTwoPoints = getCubeTwoPoints();
        }

        private Point[] getCubeOnePoints() {
            Point[] points = new Point[4];
            points[0] = new Point(x, y);
            points[1] = new Point(x + size, y);
            points[2] = new Point(x + size, y + size);
            points[3] = new Point(x, y + size);
            return points;
        }

        private Point[] getCubeTwoPoints() {
            int newX = x + shift;
            int newY = y + shift;
            Point[] points = new Point[4];
            points[0] = new Point(newX, newY);
            points[1] = new Point(newX + size, newY);
            points[2] = new Point(newX + size, newY + size);
            points[3] = new Point(newX, newY + size);
            return points;
        }

        public void shiftLeft() {
            x -= SHIFT_INC;
            for (Point p : cubeOnePoints) {
                p.x -= SHIFT_INC;
            }
            for (Point p : cubeTwoPoints) {
                p.x -= SHIFT_INC;
            }
        }

        public void shiftRight() {
            x += SHIFT_INC;
            for (Point p : cubeOnePoints) {
                p.x += SHIFT_INC;
            }
            for (Point p : cubeTwoPoints) {
                p.x += SHIFT_INC;
            }
        }

        public void drawCube(Graphics g) {
            g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
            g.drawRect(x + shift, y + shift, size, size);
            // draw connecting lines
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                g.drawLine(cubeOnePoints[i].x, cubeOnePoints[i].y, 
                        cubeTwoPoints[i].x, cubeTwoPoints[i].y);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new CubePanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: one problem, what if i wanted this in a 3d where the cube could be walked around

Comment: Jut create a `shift` method in the `Cube` class that will shift _all_ the x points or y points a certain increment then call repaint.

Comment: See my **UPDATE** for example

Comment: well that is close, dont get me wrong when i say this, I mean like minecraft when i say walked around. It's alright for you to stop there and say do it yourself to me.

Comment: Sorry I don't know minecraft. I'm not really a gamer.

Comment: in fact yea I got it from here because I realize that is handled in my camera and movement class(es)

Answer (score 1):

```
package Box;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
public class Box2 extends JPanel
{

    public Box2() 
    {
        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener(){
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            paintComponent(getGraphics());

        }

        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        });

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);


        Dimension d;
        d=getSize();
        int height, width;
        height =d.height;
        width=d.width;
        int w,h;
        javax.swing.border.Border linebor =BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0xAD85FF),6 );

        g.drawRect(0,0, w=width/2, h=height/2);

        g.drawRect(w/2,h/2,w/2*2,h/2*2);

        g.drawLine(0,0,w/2,h/2);

        g.drawLine(w,h,w/2+w/2*2,h/2+h/2*2);

        g.drawLine(w,0,w/2+w/2*2,h/2);  

        g.drawLine(0,h,w/2,h/2+h/2*2);  
        //g.drawLine(0, height – borderControl, width, height – borderControl);
    }
}
```

***Now make another class for Main File***

```
package Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Box2_main extends JPanel
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Box2 cube = new Box2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cube2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(cube);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

If you change the dimensions of the window then the size of the cube will also increase/decrease.